# How to deallocate memory from a dynamic array ? C++

Tags: c++, memory

Here is my code :

```
int** tmp = new int*[l];
for(int i = 0; i < l; i++)
    tmp[i] = new int[h];


for(int i=0;i< l;i++)
    delete[] tmp[i];
delete[] tmp;
```

I would like to know if i'm correctly deallocation memory. The problem that i have is that when i check the process of my program on the task manager, memory wont drop.

Is it normal?

Comment: Yes, this is how you dynamically allocate and free memory. "CPU won't drop" - and then what? The C++ standard doesn't say CPU usage has to drop when you `delete[]`.

Comment: dynamic memory allocation is for memory not for cpu...

Comment: Use std::vector. Really. It's out there for you.

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake, its not CPU, its memory... Memory dont drop

Comment: @user2076231 that's not surprising either. Memory management on modern OSes is a complex beast, don't try to reason about it based on a simple `new[] ... delete[]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code above is ok, altough in general it's the sort of terrible thing you hope you'll never encounter in a codebase you have to work on.

`std::vector` or `boost::multi_array` would be both better choices here, and they destroy without all that unnecessary error prone code. Basically if you have to wonder what the code is doing and whether it's correct, then something is wrong with it already.

CPU load is not connected to memory allocations directly and it's just a whole another problem you have with your code. Some loop that's endlessly polling the OS for something might be a reason for that; I have no information to what your code is doing besides allocating and deallocating memory, so it's hard to tell what could be improved.

---

After your comment... don't rely on task manager to tell you *real* memory usage of a program. Use a specialized leak detector for that. As @H2CO3 pointed out, OS might not immediately report `deleted` memory as free.

Comment: Alone the sentence "Basically if you have to wonder what the code is doing and whether it's correct, then something is wrong with it already." deserves +1 ;)

Answer (score 2):

In its barebone implementation, `new` and `delete` are just sugar over `malloc` and `free` (from the C library), so we will reason about those instead.

Operating Systems usually provide primitives to (de)allocate memory, however those primitives:

- are not as fine-grained as `malloc` and `free`: they work by 4K blocks, for example
- are relatively expansive: notably, they often zero-out the memory

As a result, most implementations of `malloc` and `free` are not simple one-line wrappers around OS primitives, but instead will keep a pool of allocated pages and handle most requests internally. Some implementations even have a per-thread pool to avoid contention (such as `jemalloc`) or multiple pools with per-thread affinity (such as `tcmalloc`).

This results:

- in faster `malloc`/`free` calls
- at the expense of memory footprint of the process being slightly higher than strictly needed

*Note: and I have not touched on fragmentation yet...*